# problem converting int to float and int to string python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

Guys I tried a couple of ways to solve a problem I am having.
My program works well without decimal numbers.

**I want to get an answer with decimal points.**

So each time i type in the decimal point, there is an error. 
 This is what I tried:

```
    from __future__ import  division
def bmi ():   ##  bmi = body mass index
    print " program to calculate person BMI"
    name = raw_input(" Hi welcome , what is your name ? : ")
    print " welcome %s " % name 
    weight = raw_input (" your weight(kg) : ")
    height = raw_input  ("your height (m): ")
    bmi =  int(weight)
    bmi_1 = int(height)
    if bmi/bmi_1**2 <= (25): 
        print " your ibm is : %d , you are not overweight "%(  bmi/bmi_1**2)
    elif  bmi/bmi_1**2 >= 24:
         print " your iibm is : %d  , sorry you are overweight" % (  bmi/bmi_1**2)
    else :
         print " sorry mistake, try again  "
```

Comment: Have you tried in built `str()` or `float()` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
float()
```

and

```
str()
```

Will do the trick.

Comment: yes i tried to :     bmi =  float(weight)
                           bmi_1 = int(float(height))

Comment: @mg777 bmi = float (input ("..."))

Comment: @mg777 glad to hear. You can check it off as the correct answer so others searching know.